# What does 'encore' mean in this sentence?

Tags: sens, adverbes

It is from a nineteenth-century short story:

> Dans le fond le plus reculé d'une province reculée de la France vivait un homme nommé Augur. Son père, honnête fermier, avait vu prospérer sa famille non moins que ses affaires ; et neuf enfants, tous enchantés de vivre, lui promettaient, avec une postérité digne des temps anciens, des soins multipliés pour sa vieillesse, sans qu'aucune inquiétude **encore** fût venue troubler sa sécurité pour l'avenir'.

Is it perhaps just an unfamiliar way of saying 'aucune autre inquiétude'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase is a little convoluted.

***Encore*** might be moved after ***que*** that way:

> *[...] sans qu'encore aucune inquiétude fût venue troubler sa sécurité pour l'avenir.*

Modern French would be:

> *[...] sans qu'aucune inquiétude ne soit encore venue troubler sa sécurité pour l'avenir.*

Here is a somewhat similar construction, although simpler (bold is mine):

> *Sur le plan sentimental comme sur le plan diplomatique, Madame l'Ambassadrice dispose du deuxième secrétaire, mais celui dont elle voudrait disposer, celui à qui elle disait tout à l’heure que c’est lui qui d’elle « dispose », le premier secrétaire — qui dans un mois, **sans qu’encore elle s’en doute**, va signer son contrat de mariage — est plus que jamais inaccessible [...]*
> Charles Du Bos, *Grandeur et misère de Benjamin Constant*, 1946

The phrase means: **without her suspecting it yet**.

Comment: I'm inclined to read it rather as Tom did: 'other'. *Encore du vin !* *Une inquiétude encore !* Is this very unlikely?

Comment: @LukeSawczak I understand *encore* to be more like "(not) yet" than "(once) again/more" here but your question demonstrates the phrasing is convoluted.

Comment: @jlliagre Thank you, it's entirely the fact that the « encore » comes before the verb rather than after it that gives me pause - and perhaps creates a muddle between the '(not) yet' and '(once) again / more' nuances

Comment: @Luke What would the meaning be if _encore_ meant ‘other’ here? “Nine children promised plentiful care for him in his old age, _no other disquiet_ yet troubling his security for the future” – other than what? Having nine children surely isn’t a form of ‘disquiet’ or ill omen. Reading it as _pas encore_ makes much more sense here: he had nine children, which boded well for his old age, and at this point, nothing _had yet_ troubled this security for his future. (The implication being that later in the story, something _will_ do so, perhaps the death of all his children or similar.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Quite right; I didn't think at all about the context, only the individual words' meanings! jlliagre's comment is all the more to the point, then.

Answer (score 1):

Although the dictionary is not as prescriptive as to include quasi negative constructions in the following definition, it seems to me that this latter, considering the negative nature of « sans », does apply.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/encore)) − 2. [En constr. négative] [Pour indiquer la prolongation de l'état négatif, en attendant la possibilité d'affirmer son changement en état positif]
> •  Rien ne bougeait encore dans les rues engourdies d'Orsenna, les grands éventails des palmes s'épanouissaient plus larges au-dessus des murs aveugles (Gracq, Syrtes,1951, p. 12)
> • Les yeux sur la table, tous quatre maintenant se faisaient petits, tandis qu'elle les tenait sous ses anciennes savates boueuses de la rue de la Goutte-d'Or, avec l'emportement de sa toute-puissance. Et elle ne désarma pas encore : ... Zola, Nana,1880, p. 1366.
> • Il attendait, avec ce serrement de cœur que tout musicien éprouve, au moment où la baguette du chef se lève et où le fleuve de musique se ramasse en silence, prêt à briser sa digue. Jamais il n'avait encore entendu son œuvre à l'orchestre. Rolland, Jean-Christophe,La Révolte, 1907, p. 503.

The negative import of « sans » in construction with « encore » is found in the  construction « [sans jamais encore](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sans%20jamais%20encore%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) ».

In the sentence of the OP, the prolongation of the negative state is the prolongation of the absence of ills such as sickness and  impoverishment, (sans aucune inquiétude); the possibility of a change is quite reasonnable: sickness is a likely candidate.